# How to surf using https in all the googles services?

Tags: google-chrome, https

I would like to surf using HTTPS in all the services of google, the reader the searching etc. currently I set my searching using the https and gmail. Is there any way to configure chrome to search if https is available and if not it will use http.

If not how can I define to google to supply me content only over SSL ?

Comment: Since 2013 Google has served all its products over HTTPS connections.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry! I don't think Google has such settings to enable HTTPS all over its services.

Alternatively you can use a extension called [HTTPS everywhere](https://www.eff.org/https-everywhere).

[image: Download HTTPS Everywhere]

Once you install it this extension it will try to first access the HTTPS address then fallback to HTTP one of any particular website you visit.

[image: HTTPS Everywhere in Google Chrome]

The local icon will appear if the website supports HTTPS totally or partially. This extension is also available for [Firefox](https://www.eff.org/https-everywhere). <s>If you really only want **Google Services** (and not other websites), then you can change some settings to get exactly what you want.</s> Sorry, this feature is not currently available for Chrome, but is available in Firefox, actually HTTPS Everywhere is currently in beta. If you use Firefox then you can try this feature.